# Kubernetes: Rsycning the Minikube Mount Directory

Tags: linux, kubernetes, minikube

So I was able to use `minikube mount /my-directory` to mount a volume in my minikube vm to reflect my local directory. However I found out that I wasn't able to make any changes to this directory inside minikube (called `/mount-9p`).

I'm attempting to create a container that would rsync the `/mount-9p` directory with another directory that I can run my executables in, but am running into this error: `Couldn't watch /mount-9p/src: Unknown error 526`

Is there anyway to override this or a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and there is currently a PR to fix it here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/1293

If you build minikube from that PR you should be good to go.  This patch should also be in minikube's next release v0.18.0.